# MIPS 2-Way Cache

Tags: mips, computer-science, cpu-architecture, cpu-cache

I've got a cache for a MIPS 64 bit architecture, 2-way of 4KB per block and lines of 16 words (for every block).
I have to determine:

1. *[ TAG | Index | Offset ]*

   Bit sizes for every field
2. How many bit is the entire memory made of?

---

I've got no clue if what I've done is correct since I don't have the results, since we are working with 64bit MIPS and not 32 I thought that a word would have been made out of 8 bytes instead of 4.

I've calculated the numbers of blocks by doing `4KB / (16 words * 8 byte)` = `32`

Then I've done `32 / 2-way`= `16` --> 4 bit of *INDEX*

Then I got word and byte offset as follows:

16 words --> 4 bit *word offset*

8 byte   --> 3 bit *byte offset*

Finally I calculated the TAG as `64 - 4(index) - 4(word offset) - 3 (byte offset)` = `53 bit`

And the total number of bit would have been `53 tag + 64 + 1 validate` = `118` which multiplied by the number of blocks(32) would have given 3776 bit.

I'm not completely sure about the result, can someone help me with this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part of the question is not very clear, I'll try to make a best guess.

Assumption : Cache size is 4KB, word is 64 bits, memory is byte addressing.

Information  : Cache line is 16 words wide, and its a 2-way set assoc cache.

```
Cacheline size = 16 word * 64 bits (8 byte) = 128 byte
Number of cachelines = 4 KB/128 B = 32
Number of blocks = 32 / 2 (2-way) = 16
As the memory is byte addressable, least 3 bits of the address can be ignored.
Next 4 bytes will be used to offset in a word in the 16 word cacheline.
Next bit of the address is ignored because its 2-way assoc
As there are 16 blocks, next 4 bits will be used to index a block.
That leaves 64 - (4 + 1 + 4 + 3) = 52 bits for the TAG.

TAG - 52 bits [bits 12 to 63]
Index - 4 bits [bits 8 to 11]
Offset - 4 bits [bits 3 to 6]
```

Its bit hard to answer to the second question as a cache would typically have extra bits per cacheline, like valid bits etc. For the sake of simplicity lets assume this cache only has a TAG per cacheline. This gives us 52 bits * 16 blocks * 2 lines in a block = 1664 bits = 208 bytes.

Therefore the whole cache size would be

```
= 4 KB + 208 B
= 4096 B + 208 B
= 4304 Bytes
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, sorry if the question wasn't too clear but thats how my professor wrote it...I myself had problem understanding it. For what it's worth a colleague of mine calculated the number of lines as (2^12) / (16 * 8) which gives 32 lines, then he got bit for line = 5 bit, bit per word = 4 bit and byte offset = 3 bit. TAG = 64 - (5+4+3) = 52. does it seems possible to you??

Comment: Its a 2-way set assoc cache. Therefore you need to mask off another bit for this. That's why I have 51 bits for the TAG. Rest of your colleague's calculations seems ok.

Comment: One last thing if you don't mind me asking, with all the informations given remaining the same as stated above, with a 4-way cache, what would have changed?

Comment: There was a bug in my solution, Fixed it now, please accept my apologies. If you follow the step by step logic I've explained above, when the cache is 4-way. you'll have 8 blocks. you'll need to mask off 2 bits for the set. And you'll only need 3 bits for the index. This leaves 64 - (3 + 2 + 4 + 3) = 52 bits for the TAG

Comment: Thank you so much, also for the fix above :D